# How do I merge dataframe column headers into a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that has been concatenated from ESPN. Currently, the kick-off time are coming in as the column headers. I need assistance on the logic needed to combine the teams into one column and the associated kick off times into another column. Thank you in advance!

The input data

```
dfs = pd.read_html("https://www.espn.com/nfl/lines")
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df
```

The current output I have:

```
9:30 AM REC (ATS)   LINE    OPEN    ML  FPI 1:00 PM 4:05 PM 4:25 PM 8:20 PM 8:15 PM
0   New York Jets   1-3 (1-3-0) 45.0    43.5    130 42.8%   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   Atlanta Falcons 1-3 (1-3-0) -2.5    -2.5    -150    56.9%   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 3-1 (3-1-0) -3.0    -3.0    -150    53.6%   Green Bay Packers   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 3-1 (2-2-0) 50.5    49.5    130 46.0%   Cincinnati Bengals  NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 0-4 (2-2-0) 49.5    49.0    350 26.1%   Detroit Lions   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 1-3 (2-2-0) -10.0   -10.0   -450    73.7%   Minnesota Vikings   NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 3-1 (3-1-0) -1.0    1.0 -115    49.0%   Denver Broncos  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 1-3 (1-3-0) 39.5    39.5    -105    50.6%   Pittsburgh Steelers NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 1-3 (2-2-0) 48.0    47.5    360 24.9%   Miami Dolphins  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 3-1 (1-3-0) -10.0   -10.0   -475    74.9%   Tampa Bay Buccaneers    NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 2-2 (2-2-0) -2.0    --  -140    57.0%   New Orleans Saints  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 2-2 (1-3-0) 43.5    --  120 42.7%   Washington  NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 1-3 (1-3-0) 44.5    44.5    140 35.0%   Philadelphia Eagles NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 3-1 (3-1-0) -3.0    -3.0    -160    64.7%   Carolina Panthers   NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 2-2 (2-2-0) -4.5    -3.5    -210    61.2%   Tennessee Titans    NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 0-4 (1-3-0) 48.5    48.0    175 38.4%   Jacksonville Jaguars    NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 1-3 (2-2-0) -9.0    -9.0    -430    68.6%   New England Patriots    NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 1-3 (2-2-0) 39.5    39.0    330 31.1%   Houston Texans  NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 2-2 (2-2-0) 44.5    --  200 36.0%   NaN Chicago Bears   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 3-1 (2-2-0) -5.5    --  -240    63.8%   NaN Las Vegas Raiders   NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 3-1 (3-1-0) 47.0    46.5    115 44.8%   NaN Cleveland Browns    NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 3-1 (3-1-0) -2.0    1.0 -135    54.8%   NaN Los Angeles Chargers    NaN NaN NaN
0   NaN 1-3 (2-2-0) 52.0    49.5    260 26.8%   NaN NaN New York Giants NaN NaN
1   NaN 3-1 (4-0-0) -7.0    -7.0    -330    73.0%   NaN NaN Dallas Cowboys  NaN NaN
0   NaN 2-2 (1-3-0) 49.0    49.0    190 36.6%   NaN NaN San Francisco 49ers NaN NaN
1   NaN 4-0 (3-1-0) -4.5    -4.5    -230    63.1%   NaN NaN Arizona Cardinals   NaN NaN
0   NaN 3-1 (3-1-0) 56.5    56.5    125 50.6%   NaN NaN NaN Buffalo Bills   NaN
1   NaN 2-2 (1-3-0) -2.5    -2.5    -145    49.0%   NaN NaN NaN Kansas City Chiefs  NaN
0   NaN 1-3 (2-2-0) 46.0    45.5    250 32.5%   NaN NaN NaN NaN Indianapolis Colts
1   NaN 3-1 (2-2-0) -7.0    -7.0    -320    67.2%   NaN NaN NaN NaN Baltimore Ravens
```

This is what I would like the dataframe to look like (done in excel)  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLJPj.png)

Comment: Please clarify what your input data looks like. Perhaps a few example rows.

Comment: I updated the original question - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change to your code:

```
dfs = pd.read_html("https://www.espn.com/nfl/lines")
dfs2 = [d.assign(kickoff = d.columns[0]).rename(columns={d.columns[0]:'TEAMS'}) for d in dfs]
df = pd.concat(dfs2)
df
```

The `dfs2 = ...` line moves the value in the name of the first column to a new column 'kickoff', and renames the first column to be 'TEAMS'

output:

```
    TEAMS                 REC (ATS)      LINE  OPEN      ML  FPI    kickoff
--  --------------------  -----------  ------  ------  ----  -----  ---------
 0  Green Bay Packers     3-1 (3-1-0)    -2    -2.0    -130  53.6%  1:00 PM
 1  Cincinnati Bengals    3-1 (2-2-0)    50    49.5     110  46.1%  1:00 PM
 0  Detroit Lions         0-4 (2-2-0)    49.5  49.0     350  26.1%  1:00 PM
 1  Minnesota Vikings     1-3 (2-2-0)   -10    -10.0   -450  73.7%  1:00 PM
 0  Denver Broncos        3-1 (3-1-0)    -1.5  1.0     -130  50.8%  1:00 PM
 1  Pittsburgh Steelers   1-3 (1-3-0)    39.5  39.0     110  48.8%  1:00 PM
 0  Miami Dolphins        1-3 (2-2-0)    48    47.5     450  24.8%  1:00 PM
 1  Tampa Bay Buccaneers  3-1 (1-3-0)   -11    -10.0   -650  75.0%  1:00 PM
 0  New Orleans Saints    2-2 (2-2-0)    -2.5  --      -135  56.9%  1:00 PM
 1  Washington            2-2 (1-3-0)    43.5  --       115  42.7%  1:00 PM
 0  Philadelphia Eagles   1-3 (1-3-0)    46    44.5     120  35.0%  1:00 PM
 1  Carolina Panthers     3-1 (3-1-0)    -2.5  -2.5    -140  64.7%  1:00 PM
 0  Tennessee Titans      2-2 (2-2-0)    -4    -3.5    -210  61.2%  1:00 PM
 1  Jacksonville Jaguars  0-4 (1-3-0)    48.5  48.0     175  38.5%  1:00 PM
 0  New England Patriots  1-3 (2-2-0)    -8    -8.0    -380  69.1%  1:00 PM
 1  Houston Texans        1-3 (2-2-0)    39    39.0     300  30.6%  1:00 PM
 0  Chicago Bears         2-2 (2-2-0)    46    --       205  36.1%  4:05 PM
 1  Las Vegas Raiders     3-1 (2-2-0)    -5.5  --      -250  63.6%  4:05 PM
 0  Cleveland Browns      3-1 (3-1-0)    47    46.5     115  44.8%  4:05 PM
 1  Los Angeles Chargers  3-1 (3-1-0)    -2.5  1.0     -135  54.8%  4:05 PM
 0  New York Giants       1-3 (2-2-0)    52.5  49.5     260  26.9%  4:25 PM
 1  Dallas Cowboys        3-1 (4-0-0)    -7    -7.0    -330  72.9%  4:25 PM
 0  San Francisco 49ers   2-2 (1-3-0)    48.5  48.5     205  35.6%  4:25 PM
 1  Arizona Cardinals     4-0 (3-1-0)    -5    -4.5    -250  64.1%  4:25 PM
 0  Buffalo Bills         3-1 (3-1-0)    56.5  56.5     130  50.6%  8:20 PM
 1  Kansas City Chiefs    2-2 (1-3-0)    -3    -2.5    -150  49.0%  8:20 PM
 0  Indianapolis Colts    1-3 (2-2-0)    46    45.5     260  32.5%  8:15 PM
 1  Baltimore Ravens      3-1 (2-2-0)    -7    -7.0    -330  67.2%  8:15 PM
```